# Not allow to send email on behalf of my client on office365

Tags: c#, email, office365, exchange-server

I have tried to send email to my client's customers with my client from address(info@myclient.com). 
and my client has already configured my smtp server via SPF to their domain.
Following is C# code written to send the email.

```
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
 //set the addresses           
 mail.From = new MailAddress("info@mycient.com");
 mail.To.Add("krishna.menan@gmail.com");
 mail.Subject = "This is an email";
 mail.Body = "this is a sample body with html in it. <b>This is bold</b> 
<font color=#336699>This is blue</font>";
 mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
 SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
 System.Net.NetworkCredential networkCredentialRFE = new 
 System.Net.NetworkCredential("kirshna@mycomapny.com", "Password123");
  smtp.Credentials = networkCredentialRFE;
 smtp.Host = "outlook.office365.com";
 smtp.EnableSsl = true;
 smtp.Port = 587; 
 smtp.Send(mail);
```

Following is error I am getting: 
 Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the taskuser you are using has the proper "send as" permissions, see "[Give mailbox permissions to another user in Office 365 - Admin Help](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Give-mailbox-permissions-to-another-user-in-Office-365-Admin-Help-1dbcf12f-a9de-4d1d-b0b3-a227f8a736d8)".